# "Concrete Mathematics" book I don't understand radix 2 explanation for Josephus problem

Tags: induction

I started reading the book Concrete Mathematics 2nd edition and there is a conversion I don't understand(is in page 11 of the book), it says:

Powers of 2 played an important role in our nding the solution, so it's
natural to look at the radix 2 representations of $n$ and $J(n)$. Suppose $n$'s
binary expansion is

$n = (b_m b_{m-1} ... b_1 b_0)_2$;

that is,

$n = b_m2^m + b_{m-1}2^{m-1} + · · · + b_{1}2 + b_0;$

> So far this part is clear to me, is the classic binary notation: $1\cdot 2^0+0\cdot 2^1+1\cdot 2^2+\cdots$

where each $b_i$ is either $0$ or $1$ and where the leading bit $b_m$ is 1. Recalling that $n = 2^m + l$, we have, successively,

$n = (1 b_{m-1} b_{m-2} ... b_1 b_0)_2 ;$

$l = (0 b_{m-1} b_{m-2} ... b_1 b_0)_2 ;$

$2l = (b_{m-1} b_{m-2} ... b_1 b_0 0)_2 ;$

$2l + 1 = (b_{m-1} b_{m-2} ... b_1 b_0 1)_2 ;$

$J(n) = (b_{m-1} b_{m-2} ... b_1 b_0 b_m)_2 :$

> These are the inductions I just don't get, I don't see the explanation to those ones and zero values $n$, $L$, $2L$ and $2L+1$

Comment: The second formula should end in $b_1\,2+b_0$.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Also, as I don't have the book at hand, what is denoted $J(n)$?

Comment: why the values on the right for n, l, 2l, 2l+1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- $n = (1 b_{m-1} b_{m-2} ... b_1 b_0)_2$: the hypothesis is that the leading bit is $1$.
- $l = (0 b_{m-1} b_{m-2} ... b_1 b_0)_2$: by definition $n=b^m+l$, and, writing this in base $2$, we have
  $$(1 b_{m-1} b_{m-2} ... b_1 b_0)_2=\underbrace{(1 0 0 ... 0 0)_2}_{=b^m}+\underbrace{(0 b_{m-1} b_{m-2} ... b_1 b_0)_2}_{\text{so this is }\: l}$$
- $2l = (b_{m-1} b_{m-2} ... b_1 b_0 0)_2$: multipliying by the base amounts so shifting the bits one step on the left (just  like multiplying by $10$ in the decimal system is done by adding a final $0$.
- $2l + 1 = (b_{m-1} b_{m-2} ... b_1 b_0 1)_2$:
  $$2l+1=(b_{m-1} b_{m-2} ... b_1 b_0 0)_2+ (00 ... 0 01)_2.$$

Is it clearer?

Comment: `the hypothesis is that the leading bit is 1.` But is not, the leading bit is $m$ and what the equation is saying is that $m-1$ contains a bit with value 1, which is not true, because for example:

when $n=10$
then $1*2^{m-1}=4$ which is not true, as the matter fact, for m-1 the bit should be zero.

Comment: The leading bit is $b_m$, and $m$ is just an ordinal, used  to denote the rank of the bit.

Answer (score 1):

The bits for $n$ reflect the fact that the leading bit must be a $1$ or we would have a shorter number.  It is like not writing $2$ in base $10$ as $02$.  That $1$ is in the $2^m$ place, so we can subtract $2^m$ from $n$ to get $l$ and have $l$ look just like $n$ except the leading $1$ is deleted.  That can result in leading zeros in $l$.  Multiplying by $2$ in base $2$ just appends a zero on the right, which is the source of the $2l$ equation.  As $2l$ is even, it has a $0$ in the ones bit so we can add $1$ without carrying, which is the source of the $2l+1$ equation.  You have not defined $J(n)$ so I can't help there.

Comment: `The bits for n reflect the fact that the leading bit must be a 1 or we would have a shorter number. `

Not true, if $n = 10$ then "m = 3" and $m - 1$($2^2$) with the bit one should in reality be zero

Comment: @Eduardo: I added a note that $l$ could have leading zeros, which I think is what you were getting at.  If $n=10_{10}=1010_2$ then $m=3$ and $l=010_2$, $2l=100_2, 2l+1=101_2$

Answer (score 0):

$$n = 2^m+l\tag{1}$$ where $2^m$ is the largest power of $2$ not exceeding $n$.

It results then $$l<2^m$$
Now, from $(1)$ and $n=b_m2^m+b_{m-1}2^{m-1} + \dots+b_0$, it follows that
$$b_m2^m+b_{m-1}2^{m-1} + \dots+b_0=2^m+l$$
that splits into:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
b_m2^m=2^m\\
b_{m-1}2^{m-1} + \dots+b_0=l
\end{cases}
\implies\\\implies\begin{cases}
b_m=1\\
2l+1=\color{blue}2(b_{m-1}2^{m-1} + \dots+b_0)\color{blue}{+1}=b_{m-1}2^m + \dots+b_02+1
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
that joins into $$2l+1=b_{m-1}2^m + \dots+b_02+b_m$$

But $J(n)=2l+1$, then
$$J(n)=b_{m-1}2^m + \dots+b_02+b_m$$

Comment: How did you split the equation into two parts? (`that splits into:`)
How did you join the equation? (`that joins into:`)